# Triggering an automation / shortcut on iPhone after a call is over

Tags: iphone, automation, shortcuts-app

I would like to run an automation or a shortcut every time I finish an incoming call or an outgoing call. What is the trigger I should use? Does such kind of a trigger even exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/communication-triggers-apdd711f9dff/4.0/ios/14.0) in the Apple support documentation which defines communication triggers for messages and emails right now. There are no communication triggers for calls. So I believe we have no option but to wait and check if Apple plans to add triggers for calls.